# requirement for "pip install git+[git repo]"?

Tags: python, git, pip

Does anyone know if it is required that a Python repository has `setup.py` script in root directory in order for `pip install git+[git repo]` to work?  How does `pip` find dependent packages from the source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Dependent packages are looked up via said setup.py (`setup_requires` and `install_requires`).

Comment: What if a package depends on another third-party package that is not included in PyPI but publicly available on Github?  How should I write `install_requires` in this case?

Comment: See https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files